# laravel with dropzone.js to upload images won't work

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js, laravel-5.3

I amusing dropzone.js to copy the dropped images to a folder in public of laravel project. but it wont work. what am i missing here?

below is my view.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminProductsController@store', 'files'=>true , 'class'=>'dropzone dz-square', 'id'=>'dropzone-example']) !!}

                            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and here is the controller update section.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
        return $path;
    }
```

Comment: show Your js part

Comment: are sure that your images are In $request?

Comment: dd($request->file('avatar')) or $request->hasFile('avatar') in your controller

Comment: if put that code on store method and it gives out null